Why would Valya deny the Harkonnens a Truthsayer?
In the Hidden Hand, the first episode of the prequel series Dune: Prophecy, Mother Superior Valya denies a request to assign a Truthsayer to House Harkonnen- for the fourth time.
Is there a reason she should do this? Would it not be to her advantage to have someone loyal to her watching the head of the Harkonnen family?

My guess is that Valya herself is a Harkonnen and there is no Truthsayer she can trust not to spy on Harkonnens for someone else. But that's just a guess. I hope someone comes and gives a canonical answer.

There is, AFAIK, no canonical answer as the series diverges considerably from the Schools of Dune book series on which it is loosely based. In the books Valya is working to rebuild Harkonnen prestige whereas in the tv series she is actively antagonistic to her family.
